# best method of making an array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I'm new to programming and am a bit unsure about how to write my own for loop. This is what I would like please?

Let us subdivide interval `[0,1]` into **`n`** points `x0=0,...,xn−1=1`.

Write a function `compute_discrete_u(epsilon, n)` that returns two numpy arrays:

`x_array` contains the coordinates of the ***`n`*** points
u_array contains the discrete values of ***`u`*** at these points.

```
u(x)=sin(1x+ϵ)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please tag which language you're referring to. You're more likely to get answers that way

Comment: From "two numpy arrays" I infer python :)

Comment: As @AP. pointed out, you'll get more answers with more appropriate tags.  You're also liable to get more and better answers if you include more details that show you've put some time and effort into solving the problem yourself.  Specifically, what have you tried?  What were the results?  How were they not the results you expected?

Comment: Further to @David, you may want to invest the time and read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @boardrider more appropriate to the OP, but thanks I guess...  I was just summarizing the 2nd article.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need a for loop at all. You want to use numpy, so you can use the vectorized operations that numpy is built upon.

Here's the function you are literally asking for (**and most likely not how you should solve your problem**):

```
# Do NOT use this.
import numpy as np

def compute_discrete_u(epsilon, n):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
    return x, np.sin(x + expsilon)
```

That's quite an awkward API. From a design point-of-view, you are mixing two responsibilities in the function:

1. Generating a certain `x` vector
2. Calculating a `u` vector based on a mathematical function.

You should not do this for complexity and reusability reasons. What if you want a non-uniform `x` later on?

**So here's what you should do:**

```
import numpy as np

def compute_u(x, epsilon):
    return np.sin(x + epsilon)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=101)
u = compute_u(x, epsilon=1e-3)
```

This is more easy to understand because the function is just the mathematical function. Additionally, you can compute u for any x array (or single float) you like. If you do not need `compute_u` elsewhere, you may even completely drop it and write `u = np.sin(x + epsilon)`